# Modx plugin caching

Tags: caching, plugins, modx

Working on a MODx Revo based site and trying to write a simlpe plugin (inspired by 'template switcher plugin written in the past for Evo). Below is the code

```
if (isset($_GET['template'])) {
   $template_id=$_GET['template'];

   if(isset($template_id)){
       $template = $modx->getObject('modTemplate', $template_id);
       $modx->resource->template = $template->get('id'); 
   }

}
```

Eventually the plugin will include much more checks etc, however for now I just want to make sure it works. Idea is simple, it's supposed to get different template for a page based on template param provided with the url. And the problem that prevents it from working as I want it to is modx caching.

My question is, how can I manipulate cache (clear/reload?) on this particular scenario so the plugin does its job?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
$modx->executeProcessor(array(
   'location' => 'system',
   'action' => 'clearCache',
));
```

I think, what you might actually want to do is investigate changing your page template in a plugin rather than a snippet. take a look at the OnWebPagePrerender event. http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/OnWebPagePrerender

Also, do some testing, while some events are listed and available in modx, not all of them are actually implemented yet [i.e. won't work]  [also take a peek at that parent page: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Plugins]

*UPDATE***

hmm - ok, give this a try:

```
/* refresh all the core partitions */
$modx->cacheManager->refresh();
```

note that after reading the docs here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Caching ther are different methods available for different versions of modx, some depreciated. ... so definitely scan the docs for the appropriate method for your version of modx.

Comment: executeProcessor actually seems to be an undefined method in Revo

Comment: hmmm...  I didn't test that, but took a look at the docs instead. see my updates above.